# Как перевести миграции в актуальное состояние?

Tags: django, sqlite

Модифицировал модели в django, и вылезла ошибка пришлось откатить миграции, но теперь

```
python manage.py migrate
```

не работает, ведь пытается запустить уже готовые миграции
Прилагаю текст ошибки

```
    Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, social_django, trips
Running migrations:
  Applying trips.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 421, in execute       
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table "trips_country" already exists

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute       
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv     
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration 
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 331, in create_model   
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 145, in execute        
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 421, in execute       
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "trips_country" already exists
```

БД - sqlite

Comment: каким образом ты откатил миграции?

Comment: @AndreyMaslov имел ввиду удалил, но в бд они остались

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это плохая идея просто грохнуть миграции, без изменения БД.
Если хочется откатить данные и изменить миграции, то необходимо сначала откатить их, например

```
django-admin migrate [app_label] [migration_name]
```

т.е. указываешь ту миграцию до которой хочешь откатиться и так по всем приложениям. После этого можно удалять миграции, вносить какие-то изменения в БД и формировать новые.

Если есть возможность, то восстанови миграции (из гит, например) откати до нужных, после этого грохай, формируй новые и применяй их.

Если такой возможности нет, то можно пойти следующим путем:
Подключиться к БД и поудалять таблицы, которые тебе не нужны, а так же открыть таблицу `django_migrations` и удалить оттуда все записи, которые относятся к удаленным миграциям.

Есть еще вариант - использовать `SeparateDatabaseAndState`
т.е. в сформированных миграциях ты разделяешь код, который джанго помечает как сделанные изменения в БД и реальные изменения, которые будут внесены в БД.

подробней о `SeparateDatabaseAndState` можно почитать тут - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.SeparateDatabaseAndState